# How to resolve '..' in a relative path in C#

Tags: c#, path

Let's say I have the following relative path as a string:

```
"foo/./my/../bar/file.txt"
```

Is there a quick way to resolve the dots (like ".." and also ".") so that the result is:

```
"foo/bar/file.txt"
```

I cannot use `Uri` as it is not an absolute path and I also cannot use `Path.GetFullPath` because this will add the path of the executing application so that I end up with:

```
 "C:\myAppPath\foo\bar\file.txt"
```

(Also it changes "/" -> "\", but I don't particularly mind this)

Comment: What do you expect it to do with `..\foo.bar`?

Comment: How do you get that "weird" relative path in the first place? RegEx may be helpful maybe...

Comment: In my case I would have to throw an exception

Comment: Would using `Path.GetFullPath` and stripping the front executing part work?

Comment: relative path to what?

Comment: Why not you parse it yourself using `string.Split`?

Comment: Just a guess: new DirectoryInfo("foo/.my/../bar/").FullName should give you the "clean" version

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: Because I expected to be able to use some existing functions. But of course I can parse it myself.

Comment: @OleAlbers: Nice one, but you still need to strip it since it included the full path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a hack,

```
string path = @"foo/./my/../bar/file.txt";
string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(path).Replace(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "");
```

You can use `Path.GetFullPath`, which returns path along with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, use `String.Replace` to remove current directory from the *resolved path*.

and you will end up with `newPath = \foo\bar\file.txt`

Comment: Works, but a bit dirty... Thanks anyway!

Comment: This does not work for `../foo`. In my opinion this should not change but this will be changed. The replace fails in this case because the last directory will be cut away from `CurrentDirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like this. Does this do the trick?

```
        string test = "foo/./my/../bar/file.txt";

        bool temp = false;
        string result = "";
        foreach (var str in test.Split('/'))
        {
            if (str.Contains(".") & str.Count(f => f=='.') == str.Length)
            {
                if (temp == false)
                    temp = true;
                else
                    temp = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!temp)
                {
                    result += str + "/";

                }
            }
        }
        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);//is there a better way to do this?
        //foo/bar/file.txt
```

Comment: Does not work if folder do have a dot characters in their name (which is legal to my understanding).

Comment: have you tried? I would assume it would just parse it normally. What did you expect to see vs what you received?

Comment: I have tried yes. Maybe I made a mistake. I will test again.

Comment: Try with a path like: `string test = "foo/my/../bar/file.txt";` . It does not work but it's definitively not related to dot character in folder names.